# Rails helpers not working in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, integration-testing, helper

I've followed the tutorial available at http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3.

It allows you to pass a subdomain option to your routes by overriding the url_for method in a helper file.
I've helper method looks like this:

```
module UrlHelper
  def with_subdomain(subdomain)
    subdomain = (subdomain || "")
    subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
    [subdomain, request.domain, request.port_string].join
  end

  def url_for(options = nil)
    if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
      options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
    end
    super
  end
end
```

so:

```
sites_homepage_url(:subdomain => "cats")
```

produces the url:

```
"http://cats.example.com/sites/1/homepage"
```

This works fine in development. In my cucumber tests, however, using:

```
sites_homepage_url(:subdomain => "cats")
```

produces:

```
"http://www.example.com/sites/1/homepage?subdomain=cats"
```

which indicates the functionality I added to url_for in the helper isn't working. Anyone got any ideas?

Edit: Formatting and added the code for the UrlHelper.

Comment: Please format the code in your question

Comment: You need to include that module in the top of your test files. For instance, `include UrlHelper` if the file is in the `/lib/url_helper.rb` location

Comment: UrlHelper is defined in app/helpers/url_helper.rb, but I get the same behavior when I explicitly include it.

Comment: Looks like something over-writing my definition of url_for in test, but not in development.

Comment: Upon further inspection (I had a buddy take a look with me) we discovered that ActionView::TestCase is requiring ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper which overwriting my url_for. Any ideas on how to make sure my module is the last version loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other solutions have not worked, you can try a harder one.

In an initializer file (like **config/initializers/url_for_patch.rb**), add this:

```
ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.class_eval do

  def with_subdomain(subdomain)
    subdomain = (subdomain || "")
    subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
    [subdomain, request.domain, request.port_string].join
  end

  alias_method_chain :url_for, :subdomain

  def url_for_with_subdomain(options = nil)
    if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
      options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
    end
    url_for_without_subdomain( options )
  end      

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add below code in your integration testing

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
```

Comment: this does not have any effect on the problem.

Comment: As mentioned above, the inclusion of that module from ActionView::TestCase is what's over-writing my version of url_for.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is defining a new `UrlHelper` module in the top-level namespace. If you're trying to override methods in `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper`, you'll need to fully qualify the module:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module UrlHelper
      def url_for
        # override as in your question
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if Rails will be entirely happy with that in app/helpers, so you might need to put this in `lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb` (if you're using autoloading from the `lib` folder), or you'll need to explicitly require the file in your `config/application.rb`