# Overriding URL helpers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing, url-helper

I have a Model (`Show`) in Rails that is accessed via a subdomain rather than a standard REST URL. In the file `app/helpers/url_helper.rb` I have the following method:

```
def show_url(show)
  root_url(subdomain: show.subdomain)
end
```

In controllers, this works perfectly. I can test it with `puts show_url(@show)` and it outputs the `subdomain` of the show as expected: `http://test.example.com`. In integration tests, however, the method doesn't work, and the default one generated by rails is used instead. If I run `puts show_url(@show)` there, I just get `http://example.com`. How do I use this custom URL helper in my integration tests?

Edit:

`routes.rb` section regarding this subdomain stuff:

```
constraints(lambda do |request|
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
  end) do
  get '/' => 'shows#show', as: :show
  get '/edit' => 'shows#edit', as: :edit_show
end
```

This is based loosely around a [Railscast on subdomain matching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?view=asciicast).

Comment: This might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160417/how-to-import-rails-helpers-in-to-the-functional-tests

Comment: I'm not getting much from that question. My issue is not with testing the URL helper (I have tests for it that work fine), but specifically that the helper method isn't available inside integration tests (however the default version generated by Rails is).

Comment: Ah, ok...maybe this question works for you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721952/rails-helpers-not-working-in-test-environment

Answer (score 1):

Try defining its route without the default "show" action:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :show, except: :show
```

Sounds a bit confusing since your model is called `Show`, but what it's doing is defining all the standard restful routes (index, new, create, edit, update, delete) except for "show", e.g.

Or another way:

```
resources :show, only: %w(index new create edit update delete)
```

Comment: Yeah, the names a tad confusing, but I get it. Let me give that a try!

Comment: So, it turns out, I don't use the `resources` method at all. I've manually defined the `show` and `edit` routes. See initial question for new code.

Comment: Ah, ok...maybe this question works for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721952/rails-helpers-not-working-in-test-environment

Comment: Tried out the accepted answer there. Do I have to include that file, or are initializers loaded automatically? I'm just getting a `NameError`: `NameError: Couldn't find UrlHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/url_helper.rb`

Comment: You would want to do it in an initializer like in the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6822329/126636

Comment: I added the initilizer, but I get the error above. Do I need to require the initializer in any way, or is it automatically loaded by Rails?

Comment: You do not need to require initializers, Rails will autoload any ruby files in `config/initializers` for you.  Are you using the code from the answer, beginning with `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.class_eval do`, not the code from the question starting with `module UrlHelper`?  It works for me without error, though I had to move the line `alias_method_chain :url_for, :subdomain` to *after* the definition of `url_for_with_subdomain`, not before it as in the linked answer.

Comment: Yes, i am using the `ActionView::Helpers:…` one, and I too had to move the `alias_method_chain` down. That's what's providing the error above.

Answer (score 0):

I would really consider doing some refactoring and renaming the Show model.

Comment: How come? Because of the common name with an action? Can you provide more information? This may be better suited as a comment than an answer.